# How to add a large number of items to an HTML selectObject

Tags: javascript, performance, createelement

I need to populate eight selectObject pulldown objects on a page with several thousand (8192) items each. I'm currently doing this in Javascript the only way I know how:

```
var iCount;
var option1;
var selectObject1 = document.getElementById('ifbchan');
for(iCount = 0; iCount < 8192; iCount++)
    {
    option1=document.createElement("option");
    option1.text = "Out " + iCount;
    option1.value=iCount;
    try
        {
        selectObject1.add(option1, selectObject1.options[null]);
        }
    catch (e)
        {
        selectObject1.add(option1, null);
        }
    }
selectObject1.selectedIndex =  0;
```

This method works properly but is extremely slow! Each of these 8K loops takes something like 10 seconds to complete. Multiply by 8 different loops and the problem is obvious. Is there any other way to add large numbers of items to a drop down list that would be faster? Any faster alternatives to the drop down control for presenting a large list of items? Thanks for any ideas.

~Tim

Comment: Why don't you generate the list server side, and serve the completed html document? also, do you really expect people to scroll through 8k items? perhaps there is a more appropriate way to lay this out?

Comment: Have you tried adding the items to a container which you also create, then add the container? That may speed things up by batching the change to the DOM?

Comment: *"Any faster alternatives to the drop down control for presenting a large list of items?"* An autocompleter?

Comment: I have no idea if it's faster, but you can replace your `createElement` and the two lines following it like this: `option1 = new Option("text", "value")`

Comment: The 8k list sounds pretty non user-friendly but it actually works out pretty well. Users select a single item from a numerically sorted list that allows them to scroll directly to the selection they want and choose it with a single click.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion T.J. I just tried the new Option("text", "val") method and it was about the same speed.

Comment: An 8000+ selectbox isn't going to be a good user experience. In your example the value it a range of intergers between 0 and 8192. If this is the case for your final use, use a check box validating for expected input or a range/slider control (jqueryui.com/slider/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jon. The item values in my example code were simplified for clarity. The actual items are 8 char strings representing audio channels sorted by channel number. Once the lists are populated the user experience has been very positive. I will investigate your suggestion about using a slider to scroll through the list with a textbox displaying the current selection. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try the following:

```
var elements = ""
var i;
for(i= 0; i < 8192; i++){
    elements += "<option value='"+ i + "'>Out " + i + "</option>";
}


document.getElementById("ifbchan").innerHTML = elements;
```

This way you only perform one action on the DOM per loop not 8000+.

Oh and here's one I prepared earlier: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ub4x/

Comment: Jon P that was it! Your code loaded the control in milliseconds rather then seconds. I thank you much for your help I really appreciate it. Have a great day. Best, Tim

Comment: No Problem. Don't forget to upvote and/or click the tick when you get the rep :-)

Answer (score 1):

Few things before the answer.

First of all I do not think that the best way to do this is a server side implementation. If you can do something on the client you should do this and not touch your server (if it is not security related).

Second thing - why exactly do you need 8000 elements in select list? Think as a user of your app, who would like to scroll through 8000 elements just to select his element? As it was mentioned before - autocomplete sounds much more suitable.

And right now is an answer:

Your original approach is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zw2CQ/3/): it takes approximately **1724** miliseconds to complete for **10000** elements (You can see this by running the script and checking inspector).

```
var start = new Date();
var n = 10000;

var iCount;
var option1;
var selectObject1 = document.getElementById('ifbchan');
for(iCount = 0; iCount < n; iCount++)
    {
    option1=document.createElement("option");
    option1.text = "Out " + iCount;
    option1.value=iCount;
    try
        {
        selectObject1.add(option1, selectObject1.options[null]);
        }
    catch (e)
        {
        selectObject1.add(option1, null);
        }
    }
selectObject1.selectedIndex =  0;

var time = new Date() - start;
console.log(time);
```

I do not like a lot of this code (it is too many lines) so I will rewrite it in jquery.

```
var start = new Date();
var n = 10000;

for (var i = 0; i<n; i++){
    $("#ifbchan").append("<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>")
}

var time = new Date() - start;
console.log(time);
```

The next fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zw2CQ/4/). Much less lines, and some time improvement. Now it is **1312** milliseconds. But it append new element in every loop.

The next [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zw2CQ/5/) get rid of this.

```
var start = new Date();
var n = 10000;

var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i<n; i++){
    html += "<option value="+i+">"+i+"</option>";
}

$("#ifbchan").append(html);

var time = new Date() - start;
console.log(time);
```

Wow, now it is only **140** milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i<n; i++){
   select.append('<option value='+i+'>'+i+'</option>');
}
```

Beware, this doesn't work in IE. See this link -

[Using innerHTML to Update a SELECT – Differences between IE and FF](https://allofetechnical.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/using-innerhtml-to-update-a-select-differences-between-ie-and-ff/)